# Cambiar dato de una lista a otra sin transformar la inicial con python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, flask

Tengo una lista llamada *datos* que contiene a su vez listas (es una lista de listas). Cada una de las listas que contiene, uno de sus valores es una fecha. Me gustaría que dependiendo del huso horario que elijan los usuarios se calcule una hora u otra para que sea la elegida por el usuario. El problema que tengo es que la lista en la que están las horas por defecto por así decirlo (la lista *datos*) también se modifica, por lo que cada vez que se refresca la página se calcula una hora nueva en base a la anterior calculada, por lo que al final la hora que le aparece al usuario no es la hora por defecto +- la hora que él haya seleccionado, si no que le aparece la hora por defecto +- (la hora que él haya seleccionado x el número de veces que haya refrescado la página).
Parece que el problema es que la lista *datos* se va machacando o algo así. Al usuario la lista que se le muestra es la *newDatos*
Dejo por aquí el código de la función que ajusta el huso horario al solicitado por el usuario:

```
datos= [['BTCUSDT','Long','Pullback en resistencia','23-Nov 09:51'],['ETHUSDT','Short','Rotura de soporte','23-Nov 07:28'], ...]

def ajustarHusoDatos(usuario):
    if husoDeUsuario(usuario)[0] == '+':
        newHora= abs(int(int(husoDeUsuario(usuario)[1])-1))
        newDatos = []
        for x in datos:
            fechaNew= datetime.strptime(x[3], "%d-%b %H:%M")
            fechaRaw= fechaNew+timedelta(hours=int(newHora))
            newFecha= str(fechaRaw.strftime("%d-%b %H:%M"))
            newDatos.append(x)
            newDatos[len(newDatos)-1][3] = newFecha
    else:
        newHora= abs(int(int(husoDeUsuario(usuario)[1])-1))
        newDatos = []
        for x in datos:
            fechaNew= datetime.strptime(x[3], "%d-%b %H:%M")
            fechaRaw= fechaNew-timedelta(hours=int(newHora))
            newFecha= str(fechaRaw.strftime("%d-%b %H:%M"))
            newDatos.append(x)
            newDatos[len(newDatos)-1][3] = newFecha

    return newDatos
```

Muchas gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que, aunque sacas una copia de la lista `datos` a otra nueva `newDatos`, cuando después agregas elementos a esta nueva haciendo

```py
newDatos.append(x)
```

estás añadiendo en realidad **una referencia** a la sub-lista original, de modo que cuando después modificas esa sublista mediante:

```py
newDatos[len(newDatos)-1][3] = newFecha
```

estarás modificando en realidad la sublista original.

La forma de evitarlo es sacar también una copia de la sublista. Esto puedes hacerlo con el método `.copy()` de las listas.

```py
newDatos.append(x.copy())
```

En este caso eso sería suficiente, pues la sublista no contiene a su vez sub-listas. Si las tuviera podrías encontrarte con el mismo problema un nivel más abajo, pues `.copy()` al crear una nueva sublista copia también referencias a los contenidos. Para un caso más general puedes usar `copy.deepcopy()`.

### Explicación gráfica

Esto es lo que estabas haciendo (en rojo son las variables locales de la función, en negro la lista global, se muestra el instante en que se han hecho ya dos `newDatos.append(x)`, pero he omitido el que se hayan modificado las fechas, para centrarse sólo en la estructura de los datos)

[image: Antes]

Si en ese momento modificas `newDatos[0][3]` para asignarle un `newFecha` lo que ocurre se muestra en la siguiente figura:

[image: Tras asignación]

Ves como la referencia que apuntaba a `'23-Nov 09:51'` (que muestro en la figura como línea discontinua, pero que en realidad Python ya ha eliminado) ahora apunta a `'23-Nov 10:51'`, pero esa referencia era la que se accedía también desde la global `datos` por lo que indirectamente se ha modificado la global. La antigua cadena `'23-Nov 09:5'` se ha quedado sin referencias que apunten a ella, por lo que pronto el recolector de basura de Python la eliminará de la memoria.

En cambio, esto es lo que pasa cuando haces `x.copy()`: se crea una nueva sublista de 4 elementos (aunque los elementos siguen siendo referencias a los originales). En la figura se muestra la primera iteración del bucle, justo tras el `newDatos.append(x.copy())`

[image: Con copy]

Y esto es lo que pasa cuando reasignas la fecha sobre esa copia, al ejecutar la instrucción `newDatos[len(newDatos)-1][3] = newFecha`

[image: Tras asignación]

como ves, la referencia que apuntaba a `'23-Nov 09:51'` ahora apunta a una nueva cadena `'23-Nov 10:51'`, pero la sub-lista original sigue apuntando a la cadena original, por lo que no se ve afectada.

Comment: Joder tío, miil gracias!! Ya lo he solucionado. Mil gracias de verdad, tanto por la respuesta como por la pedazo de explicación que has dado con los dibujos y todo. La verdad que me ha quedado bastante claro. Muchísimas gracias!